# Implement template class Stack

Tags: c++, list, templates, stack

Getting some error when implement class stack using the template class List.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

template<class T>
class Stack
{
private:
List<T> fElements;

public:

typedef typename List<T>::Iterator Iterator;

bool isEmpty() const;
int size() const;
void push( const T& aItem );
void pop();
const T& top() const;

const T& operator[]( size_t aIndex ) const;

// stack iterators
Iterator begin() const;
Iterator end() const;
Iterator rbegin() const;
Iterator rend() const;
};
```

Problem with getting implementation using the class Stack. Using the iterators

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question

Comment: You haven't defined the `Iterator` type.

Comment: Providing a `top()` method which returns elements by reference is dangerous as the topmost element may become invalid after calling `pop()`. It is very likely that one uses `top()` to fetch the topmost element followed by a `pop()`to remove that element. If the `pop()`is overseen and then the element is accessed afterward, it leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to include the list header, use lower case `list` instead of upper case `List` as well as specify the namespace std:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <list>

template<class T>
class Stack
{
private:
    std::list<T> fElements;

public:

    typedef typename std::list<T>::Iterator Iterator;

    bool isEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    void push( const T& aItem );
    void pop();
    const T top() const;

    const T &operator[]( size_t aIndex ) const;

    // stack iterators
    Iterator begin() const;
    Iterator end() const;
    Iterator rbegin() const;
    Iterator rend() const;
};
```

Comment: I did not want to include my opinion in the answer. Therefore i add this as a comment: You should let the `pop` method return the topmost element of the stack (by copy, of course) to be consistent with the `top` method. This is more convenient than having the need to use `top()` and `pop()` all the time directly after each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should include the `list` header, and c++ is a case sensitive programming language, so, it's important to declare your data types (Abstract for this one) according to stantards, and specify the std namespace.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdexcept>
    #include <list>

    template<class T>
    class Stack
    {
    private:
    std::list<T> fElements;

    public:

    typedef typename std::list<T>::Iterator Iterator;

    bool isEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    void push( const T& aItem );
    void pop();
    const T& top() const;

    const T& operator[]( size_t aIndex ) const;

    // stack iterators
    Iterator begin() const;
    Iterator end() const;
    Iterator rbegin() const;
    Iterator rend() const;
    };
```

Comment: implement the given methods for stack. I get an error during const T& operator[] (size_t aIndex) const;

Comment: The implementation of your overloaded operator (`const T & operator [] (size_t aIndex) const;`) is not shown, please, if you may, a minimal reproducible example of the block (where you have defined this last one) and the complete impeller given by your compiler (expose the complete error), I can't see where and what is your error because there are only the prototypes of your methods here.

Comment: Besides this, the implementation of the prototypes and the body of the class seems correct in my opinion, now it depends on the other blocks of your code.